# Can ${\rm inf} (A\cap B) > {\rm max} ({\rm inf} A, {\rm inf} B )$?

Tags: real-analysis

Can ${\rm inf} (A\cap B) > {\rm max} ({\rm inf} A, {\rm inf} B )$ ? It should hold for some special cases but I can't find *an example*.

Since the actual inequality is inf ${\rm inf} (A\cap B) \geqslant  {\rm max} ({\rm inf} A, {\rm inf} B )$. But I can't  find such sets, I have looked for the case if $B$ is a subset of $A$, their intersection has a single element or if $A=B$, the equality sign holds in each case.

Comment: hi Tikemys. as a hint, consider the sets $A=\{0,5\}$ and $B=\{1,5\}$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X\subseteq\textbf{R}$ be a nonempty set bounded below, hence it admits a greatest lower bound.

Suppose that $Y\subseteq X$ where $Y\neq\varnothing$. The claim is $\inf(Y) \geq \inf(X)$.

In order to prove so, let us suppose that $\inf(Y) < \inf(X)$.

By the definition of infimum, there exists some $y\in Y$ s.t. $\inf(Y)\leq y < \inf(X)$, where $y\in Y = X\cap Y$.

Then it should hold that $y < \inf(X)\leq x$ for every $x\in X$, which leads to a contradiction.

Based on such results, the proposed claim follows immediately:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
A\cap B\subseteq A\\\\
A\cap B\subseteq B
\end{cases} \Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\inf(A\cap B) \geq \inf(A)\\\\
\inf(A\cap B) \geq \inf(B)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \inf(A\cap B) \geq \max\{\inf(A),\inf(B)\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: I think the OP is thinking about sets $A,B$ with the strictly inequality. Because if $x\geqslant a$ then $x>a$ o $x=a$.

Comment: @user1027216 Indeed, I solved the problem concerning the inequality $\geq$. I will keep it though.

Answer (score 2):

Try $A=\{0,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$.